# Pandas MultiIndex or Pivot Table Dillema

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, multi-index

I currently have a Pandas dataframe with the current structure:

[image: As you can see each each region returns 3 calculations per day]

I would like to horizontally expand this dataframe and transform it to something more 'excel-ey' like below (made this by hand for now):

[image]

I can't figure out if I should be trying to utilize Pandas's `multindex` dataframe here or a simple pivot table? Maybe its not possible for pandas? Have I reached the pandas technical limit?!

The current multi-index I produce is unable to turn the regions into the primary columns with the 3 secondary columns (total trans, count greater than, count less than) beneath.

Comment: `df.pivot_table(index='DATES',columns='REGIONS')`?

Comment: To answer Ch3steR, that's what I thought originally but it doesn't actually make the columns the REGIONs, it makes those calculations the columns and the region the children: